# How to reduce bandwidth size in getting information from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript which uses Ajax to gather information from a PHP file using the GET method. It gets information from 7 different PHP files every 3 seconds. My web host started banning IPs which visit the website identifying them as attackers.
Would it help if I would make 1 PHP file for all 7 different pieces of information?

Comment: It likely would, yes.  This doesn't sound like a *bandwidth* problem so much as a problem of sending so many requests.  HTTP requests are bottlenecks anyway, so if you can get all of the information you need from *one* request instead of *seven* then you should do that.  You can still organize your server-side code into different files if you prefer, just have a single endpoint handling the request.

Comment: @David good idea. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One call to get all seven values would reduce the number of times you hit the webserver -and this might appease the host.

You could try maintaining connections rather than reconnecting -using websockets to provide a pipe between your ajax and the php code.

If the site is busy, you might want to discuss options with your host, so they can modify firewall rules.